# How to get result set or affected row after raw SQL update in Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

I am using the following raw SQL update:

```
$query = "UPDATE $table SET balance = balance + $this->sum WHERE cashbox_id = $cashboxId";

$db->execute($query);
```

Now I need the final `balance`, that has been updated, because I need to insert the changed balance in another table. How can I achieve this?

I need to use only raw SQL on this one.

Comment: You will need to run a separate query to get that information and than another one to update the record in another table. My suggestion would be to use triggers in your db, which would help you do this with less work. Or use stored procedures if possible. Otherwise the only option is to run multiple queries. Also your query seem vulnerable to SQL injection based on the provided code sample.

Comment: my bad for the non relative answer. without using models i think your best bet is triggers.
i would use models to be on the safe side

Answer (score 1):

You can use trigger to do the trick. You can define the trigger in your sql server.

Comment: But is there any way to rollback a trigger, if anything goes wrong with the transaction?